# .htaccess redirect to .www, subfolder, hide subfolder and index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to use .htaccess to redirect all requests to the `www.` version of the domain, and to the files stored in a "new" subdirectory of the root.
However, the "new" subdirectory should be hidden and also any index.php occurance in the URL. Is this possible?
Example: `http://mydomain.de/?x=100` would direct to `http://www.mydomain.de/index.php?x=100` , but only show `http://www.mydomain.de?x=100` in the browser.

So far I tried it with

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.de$
RewriteRule ^new/index.php(.*)$ /$1 \
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain\.de/new [R=301,L]
```

but that doesn't work.

Edit w/ latest code, I've commented out the lines that led to a server error:

```
# add www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
# remove /new/ from URL
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /new/(\S*)\s [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=302]  
# remove /index.php from URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC]
# redirect everything to /new/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^/?$
RewriteRule ^((?!new).*)$ http://www.xn--krisen-lsen-yfb.at/new/$1 [L]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule !^new/ new%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

With the above htaccess code, "/new" and "index.php" still remain in the URL. Also, redirect to "www." doesn't work if the URL contains parameters, like in "[http://krisen-lösen.at/new/index.php/das-team](http://krisen-l%C3%B6sen.at/new/index.php/das-team)".

Answer (score 1):

Have it like this in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# add www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# remove /new/ from URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /new/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=302]  

# remove /index.php from URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC]

# route everything to /new/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^new/ new%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: the "remove /new/" section leads to a "no input file found" (ff) or "page cannot be displayed" (ie) error; the "remove /index.php" section doesn't do anything, strangely.
The last section I had to change to
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^/?$
RewriteRule ^((?!new).*)$ http://www.mydomain.de/new/$1 [L]
in order to redirect, but the URL field contains www.mydomain.de/new/index.php/subpage , not www.mydomain.de/subpage as I hoped.

Comment: I did and described the results more detailed below the updated .htaccess code. Thanks!

Comment: Does /new also have a htaccess? If yes then please proof provide that also

Comment: Using these exact rules on my Apache I get redirected from `localhost/new/index.php/das-team` to `localhost/index.php/das-team` and then `index.php` from `/new/` gets loaded.